# Python Django Form submit button not working as desired

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to learn Django.
I am stuck on this form part. A form has been created that allows the user to create an Album object where they can fill in the Artist, Album Name, Genre and upload an Album Logo. When I fill in the fields and then click submit, it should then redirect me to the details page for that particular Album that just got created. But nothing appears to happen when clicking the submit button and the object does not get created.

Here is the models.py code that contains an Album class with 4 fields; artist, album_name, genre and album_logo.

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.ImageField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_name + " - " + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

Here is the album_form.html code which contains the actual form. I have not used crispy_forms as I am not familiar with Bootstrap though I know CSS.

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add a New Album{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <form class="formContainer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.label != 'Album logo' %}
                <label for="field{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="field{{ forloop.counter }}" name="" value="">
            {% else %}
                <label for="field{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <input type="file" id="field{{ forloop.counter }}" name="" value="" accept="image/*">
            {% endif %}
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="" value="Add">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is views.py code where I have made use of class based views and not function based views.

from django.views import generic
from .models import Album, Song

```
# Create your views here.
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'


class AlbumCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_name', 'genre', 'album_logo']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and finally this is my urls.py code:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name='music'

urlpatterns = [
    #/music/
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    #/music/5/
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

    #/music/album/add/
    path('album/add/', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add')
]
```

After clicking the submit button in the form, it should take me to the "detail" url for the primary key of the Album that got created. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py you need to override the get_success_url function in your CreateView and pass the id as an argument while redirecting.

```
class AlbumCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_name', 'genre', 'album_logo']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', args=(self.object.id,))
```

Comment: Thank you i tried this but not working. Do i need to have something set in the form action tag?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to put `action` to your `<form>` tag

Try this

```
<form class="formContainer" action='{% url 'music:album-add'%}' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Edit: Also add success url using `get_success_url` function in your `AlbumCreate` view to redirect user to album detail page, like was mentioned in above answer

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
...
class AlbumCreate(generic.CreateView):
    ...
    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('music:detail', args = (self.object.id,))
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working. Did you mean it should be action='{% url 'music:detail' %} instead?

Comment: @mp3909 no, you have to send form to your `album-add`, which is responsible for form validation and than redirect to `detail`. You forgot to include `success_urll` to your `AlbumCreate` view and I also did not noticed it

Comment: hi, still no luck even after adding the things you suggested. Can I just make sure with you one thing, the success_url thing you told me to add, should it be:             
def get_success_url(self):
  return reverse('music:detail', args=(self.object.id,))

Comment: Yes, my mistake. You cannot use get id of object in simple `success_url`, so better use `get_success_url`

Comment: ok, yes that's what I have written but still not working. After filling in the form and then clicking submit, it does not redirect me to the details page and the object is not actually created. Also, i might be wrong but doesn't the def get_absolute_url(self):
  return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})  function inside the models.py do more or less the same thing as def get_success_url(self)?

Comment: First we need to undestand, what really causes error. If object is not created as you sad, so we need to figure out what is causing it. 
1. Open form page in your browser, open code inspection (F12 usually in Chrome) and switch to the `Console` tab
2. Press submit button on the form and chech if it sends request to the server like POST http://127.0.0.1/ and your link
3. If there is no such message when you press, than form is not sending and problem is in template

Comment: 4. If there is url in console meaning that request is made, go and check what is the last lines of your server running, usually they will tell what is crashing inside 5. Post it so we can understand what a problem is @mp3909

Comment: Hi, I opened up the form page in my browser, filled it in and then pressed submit. The Console tab is showing empty, nothing in there.

Comment: @mp3909 are you sure that you tried to submit the form after openning the console? Because console will not display you requests made before opening console